# How to clear a document.write()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to clear my little `document.write` thingy,
but:
`document.clear()`
doesn't work (playcode said it was "depcreciated").

I was trying to look on google 4 the answer but all I was getting was how to clear a form input.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). and stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried?

Comment: `document.write` is extremely crude and virtually never what you want to use in the first place…

Comment: `document.write("Hello world!")` then tried `document.clear`

Comment: @deceze im trying 2 make breakout w/ ascii characters
it is wot i want 2 use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `document.body.innerHTML = ''`

Comment: Adding a little explanation along with the code will go a long way to improve this answer